# Facebook's new Javascript SDK stream.publish broken?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Using FB.ui({ method: 'stream.publish' ...})
It fails to accept my attachment media complaining it should be an array (while it is).

The old API (FB.Connect.streamPublish) accepted the format just fine, and all the other options seem to be valid.
I find the Facebook documentation to be a mess, somebody got this working with the new version?

The whole post is created as follows:

```
            var attachment = {media: new Array({type:'image',
                                         src:'http://xxxxxxx' + baseurl + 'img/facebook-share_big.png',
                                         href:'http://xxxxxxx' + baseurl}),
                             name: 'xxxxxxx',
                             description: message,
                             href: 'http://xxxxxxx' + baseurl};
            var action = [{text: 'xxxxxxx', href: 'http://xxxxxxx' + baseurl}];
            FB.ui({
                method: 'stream.publish',
                message: 'xxxxxxx',
                attachment: attachment,
                action_links: action,
                user_message_prompt: 'xxxxxxx'
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post:
http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=237121#p237121

The solution proposed is:

```
    ......
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.JSON.stringify = function (value) { return JSON.encode(value);};
    FB.init({
......
```

It worked for me (Mootools, in FF, didn't check other browsers yet)